# Difference in Accessibility Trees of Firefox and Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, accessibility

What is the difference between the accessibility trees of Google Chrome and Firefox?

I want to know how these browsers render the accessibility tree.
What is difference between the accessibility trees of these browsers, and does that difference impact the information shared to the accessibility APIs?

Comment: Hi Austine. This question is too broad for Stack Overflow. You need to ask questions where we can give you a specific answer. Do some research and ask more specific questions (i.e. why does Chrome treat this item differently to Firefox in the accessibility tree) with a code example etc. These are the sort of questions we can answer (or questions like your other question that I answered on automating screen readers). I am voting to close this question. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask as it will help you ask questions we can help with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too broad and shows no research / a specific problem to try and solve.

Comment: I voted to close, too. The question need more precisions. For the same HTML code, accessibility tree is certainly going to be different across browsers, but no one will be able to tell exactly how and what.
Be more specific, come with some code showing a difference, etc.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie, could you suggest some platforms or sites where I can find answers relating to this topic. I am trying to develop a automated screen reader testing tool for web accessibility and currently thinking about parsing the HTML code and running checks on tags to ensure they have been given a accessible property.

Comment: Look into `Puppeteer` which allows you to control a headless browser via the command line and then writing a set of rules similar to something Like `Pa11y`. There are hundreds of tools out there already that do automated testing, I would recommend using one of them instead of trying to do it yourself as this is a massive undertaking.

Comment: This may interest you: https://www.levelaccess.com/how-browsers-interact-with-screen-readers-and-where-aria-fits-in-the-mix/